# My CSS Images not working when published to Azure Site but OK locally HTML5 Bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap.css has

```
.jumbotron:after {
     content:"";
     background: url("../content/images/Banner.png");
     opacity: 0.2;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
 }
```

and it works a treat on localhost but publish to Azure and nothing

My Azure URL is https://kohphanganpoolleague.azurewebsites.net/

If I FTP to Azure Site I have this in the bootstrap.css :

```
 .jumbotron:after {
     content:"";
     background: url("../../content/images/Banner.png");
     opacity: 0.2;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
 }
```

Extra "../" ?????

Cheers, J

Comment: I do not see the style - `jumbotron:after` in the rendered Markup of  https://kohphanganpoolleague.azurewebsites.net/. I used F12 Developer tools to check the style, but was not able find the style in any of the CSS file. Can you check that?

Comment: Also one more check to do, have you published the latest styles to Azure Websites?

Comment: I just tried right clicking on the bootstrap.css and publishing it. If I right click on project and publish preview there is nothing until I change files. i.e. VS2013 suggest its all up there and published already

Comment: Can you FTP to Azure Website and check all the files are properly publishes? I mean cross check if you have bootstrap.css have that style?

Comment: OK, I just changed the font size and noticed the difference on localhost first. then i did a publish preview and it displayed that bootstrap.css was getting updated. i then published and it loaded up the site after copying up the files but no change in font, odd. anything else i change in the project is reflected and OK

Comment: Are you sure, the new file has been uploaded to server, can you FTP it and check file. Also some time browser will not detect the new change and will apply css from browser cache. Can you delete all the cache of browser and see what happens.

Comment: On a side note, it is a bad practice to update bootstrap.css directly. Your changes will be wiped if you update bootstrap nuget. Better create your own css file that is placed after bootstrap.css in the page - to override original styles.

Comment: @John, are you able to fix your problem?

Comment: If I change path to file on server it never works. I tried background: url("/content/images/Banner.png"); and also background: url("../content/images/Banner.png"); etc. But both work locally. I tried resetting CACHE in browser. Still not getting the image. Looking via FTP the image is in the directory - and also bootstrap.css is there and all ok. Must be something to do with Bundles - i'm publishing to RELEASE

Comment: Thanks trailmax, that makes sense, right now I just need to get this image to display. Could Release on Server be using Bootstrap.min.css - because its not got the new code

Comment: Sorted, if I overwrite BOOTSTRAP.MIN.CSS with my main bootstrap.css content it WORKS. This problem seems to be that I am publishing to release and Bundle.Config is using the other CSS for min for release. Looking to see best way to do this, i tried my Site.css but that never worked, i moved the .jumbotron script to there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its was related to Bundle.cs and I made the mistake of editing the bootstrap.css itself and not another file like say Site.css. When its published it was using min.css (a different CSS file)